# Can't edit site page in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using sharepoint online with sharepoint designer 2013.
and I'm trying ti edit home page in sharepoint designer but I got the following error
"Server error: Access deined"

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I couldn't reproduce your question. However, we can work together to narrow down and resolve the situation. So, please kindly provide more information below to let us work further.

1.Make sure you use the Edit and Customize page permissions. Sometimes even though you have the full control permission level, it's likely that this permission is missing. please click Settings (gear icon) on your SharePoint site, select Site Permissions>Advanced permissions settings, click Check Permissions under Permissions tab, enter your name and check now, check the permission assigned to you.

2.Whether other users with same permissions facing the same problem? View through another computer or account.

3.Whether all SharePoint sites have the same problem? You could create a new SharePoint site to check.

4.Check if the same issue occurs with other SharePoint site collections.

5.You could try to clear browser cache then restart it.

6.Try to use a different browser or your browser's InPrivate mode to see if the same error occurs.